# IS EBCDIC files are supported by Azure data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory, mainframe

Can we ingest EBCDIC files using azure data factory? if yes, which all connectors support that? Does DB2 connector support

Answer (score 0):

You can copy EBCDIC files by Copy Data activity. Data Flow can't handle EBCDIC encoded files. You can vote [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/41552131-implement-native-handling-for-ebcdic-encoded-files) for this feature.

There are many connectors support that, you can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-binary). But DB2 doesn't support it.